# Split Strings, Search and Translate Substrings JAVA

Tags: java, string, substring

I'm pretty new to Java, and I need to solve this problem for an assignment. Can anyone help me please?

The problem is we need to enter a String like "AUGUUUUCU" and then split it into three letter strings like "AUG", "UUU", "UCU".

After that I would have to iterate over these and translate them to "AUG = METIONINA", "UUU = FENILANINA", "UCU = SERINA". Can anyone help me with this?

I already found a way to split them:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        String str = "AUG-UUU-UCU";
        String delimiter = "-";
        String[] temp;
        temp = str.split(delimiter);
        for(int i =0; i < temp.length ; i++)
            System.out.println(temp[i]);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Hint: you should use the method `substring` available in class [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: Thanks it did helped me to split them :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a coder on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're supposed to take user input, then you'll need to use a Scanner:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = sc.next();
```

To split it into three-letter Strings, use an array and store the substrings in the array using a `for` loop:

```
String[] subs = new String[input.length()/3];
int index;
for (int i=0; i<input.length(); i++) {
    index = i*3;
    subs[i] = input.substring(index, index+3);
}
```

You could then iterate over the array with another `for` loop and use a `switch` statement to determine the correct output:

```
for (int i=0; i<subs.length; i++) {
    switch(subs[i]) {
        case "AUG":
            System.out.println("METIONINA");
            break;
        case "UUU":
            System.out.println("FENILANINA");
            break;
        case "UCU":
            System.out.println("SERINA");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Note the `break` statements within the `switch` block. These are important to include; without `break` statements, it will simply execute all code after the matching case.

Comment: WOOOOW, I think you just saved me xD I didn't think to use the Switch in this one I had a similar program with all if's and else's xD thank you so much xD I'm going to try it

Comment: It returns me:
Registre
AUGUUUUCU
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 12
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
 at Main.main(Main.java:13)
Got any idea?

Comment: Oh, I see what I did wrong. In the first `for` statement, instead of `i<input.length()`, it should be `i<(input.length()/3)`.

Comment: That actually did it, I really didn't know I could divide the length xD you're my savior than you soooo much :D now I'll just adjust it to more stuff instead of three :D thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array that holds the values that are to be translated.

```
translateArray = new String[3];
```

Then you could set the values of the parallel array based on the input you receive. Then you could post those values.

```
for (int i=0; i<temp.length ; i++) {
     if (temp[i] == "AUG" ) {
         translateArray[i] = "METIONINA";
     }
     if (temp[i] == "UUU") {
         translateArray[i] = "FENILANINA";
     }
     if (temp[i] == "UCU") {
         translateArray[i] = "SERINA";
     }
     System.out.println(temp[i] + " = " + translateArray[i]);
}
```

Maybe that will work better for you.

Comment: Thanks, yes I was thinking in something like that but the problem is if I put first UUU or UCU and then the AUG the translateArray is not going to change like the words xD

Comment: This should work better for you.

Answer (score 0):

To split a string into strings 3 chars long is 1 line:

```
String[] words = str.split("(?<=\\G...)");
```